# Xcode 6.1 disappearing elements of UI

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Suddenly my UI elements disappeared from the UI preview on the MainStoryBoard and got greyed.
When I build app everything is ok but I can't modify buttons and labels by drag and drop I can't even click on them

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LI0cD.png

Anyone has that issue?
Best Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check if the checkbox is enabled for the corresponding elements:

[image]